# Constrained extrema under OR conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

There is a lot of literature about  numerical methods for finding ( $\bf{x}\in \bf{R}^n$,  $\ f$ and $g_1, \ldots,g_k$ sufficiently differentiable):

$ \min f(\bf{x}) $ under $ \cap_{i=1}^k \{g_i({\bf{x}}) \le 0\}$ *-AND condition-*

but is there anything about

$ \min f(\bf{x}) $ under $ \cup_{i=1}^k \{ g_i({\bf{x}}) \le 0\}$  *-OR condition-*?

This appears in reliability problems where the first condition describes a parallel system and the second a series system.

I didn't find anything till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AND operator on the constraints makes the set of constraints a system of non-linear equations. When we have an OR operator suddenly we have a no longer such a thing. Typically this is handled using binary variables: a binary variable $b_i$ is used to indicate whether equation $i$ is turned on ($b_i=0$ means ignore this constraint, and $b_i=1$ means keep the constraint):
$$
  g_i(x) \le (1-b_i)M_i 
$$
where $M_i$ is a large enough constant to make this equation non-binding (think of it as an upper bound on $g_i$). Finally we add:
$$
  \sum_i b_i \ge 1
$$
to require that at least one constraint should hold. This makes the model a MINLP (Mixed Integer Non-Linear Program). (For an example related to reliability see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2015/12/optimality-of-small-minlp-model.html)). There are nowadays solvers that can handle those type of problems. You also see that those problems are "solved" using heuristics (including meta-heuristics). These heuristics provide "good" solutions instead of proven optimal solutions. Many reliability models I see try to keep the functions linear using more or less ingenious modeling tricks. [Here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2015/11/linearization-by-enumeration-of-small.html) is an example. This will allow the model to be solved as a straight linear MIP (Mixed Integer Program) for which powerful solvers are available.